# Would responsive design be the way to go in this case?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have coded a very complex php game with around 40 pages. I am now in the process of designing it. Would responsive design be the right choice in this case? What other options are available? Maybe I should just make three layouts (3 different stylesheets - normal, tablets and mobiles)?

It just seems like a ridiculous amount of work moving all these elements since there are so many pages.

Comment: You haven't designed the game yet? How can you test it or deal with performance issues, etc..?

Comment: I made a very basic design when I coded the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a responsive site is not that difficult from the html/css point of view, although I'm not sure how your php will affect that. You actually always have the same classes/ids, and just apply styles to them using the media queries (inside the same sheet). It would mean a lot more effort to write 3 separate sheets, but then again: depends on your code. In general, the trick is just to have good semantic, clean code (use positions wisely, for example). It takes some time to get everything organised at first, but once you have the basics structured with responsiveness in mind it gets really easy. Those 40 pages should all have the same structure, right?

Another option would be a liquid design. Instead of changing the styles, you use percentages or dynamic measures. But I strongly recommend grids, and you only have to do it once and it won't be long until everyone does responsive sites.

But if the game is complex and need some serious tweaking, you should consider doing a completely separate thing for mobile (tablets should be easy enough to adapt, your choice). It really depends on the product design, things can look very different in 320px wide. Good luck with the game!

Answer (score 0):

If the content will be the same on all the devices and you can't think of a good reason to fork the code to provide different content for different devices, responsive design is the way to go.